# for(... for Android Studio auto insert

Tags: android-studio, ide

Maybe somebody knows a plugin thats help to autoinsert pattern
`for(int i = 0;i<;i++)` into my code?

Because programmes is very lazy (not except me) and it`s boring to write the same every time

Comment: `programmes is very lazy` You seem to be as well, since you didn't google for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for that. There's a built-in live template that creates such loops for you. To use it, type `fori` and press Tab.

To see what other live templates are available and to add or change them, open Editor | Live Templates in the Settings dialog.